# SCALA contains multiple conditions on listFiles

Tags: scala, list, file, filter, exists

The following works, but I would like to add a list of conditions for the contain. That I cannot seem to effect.

```
val Files = dir
  .listFiles
  .filter(_.getName.contains("INIT"))
  .sorted
  .map(f => f.toString)
```

I would like to check for INIT and UPD and DEL in the most efficient way. All options I have tried have not yielded a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to check whether there *exists* a substring from a list of given substrings such that the filename *contains* the substring. In code:

```
val substrings = List("INIT", "UPD", "DEL")
dir
  .listFiles
  .filter(f => { 
    val n = f.getName
    substrings.exists(n.contains)
  })
  .sorted
  .map(f => f.toString)
```

Comment: Gosh, where could I have found this? You beaut. Got it actually.